# Clash between packages: lastpage, babel and microtype

Tags: babel, books, microtype, front-matter, lastpage

The following code causes an error when I try to compile it.

```
\documentclass{book}
\RequirePackage{lastpage}
\RequirePackage[polutonikogreek]{babel}
\RequirePackage[babel=true]{microtype}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

Test

\end{document}
```

The error is

> ./bac_a_sable.tex:12: Missing \endcsname inserted. 
> \MT@#1@context  l.12 \end{document}

Does the problem happen when you try? If yes, would you have a hack to solve the issue?

Thanks

Comment: well lastpage doesn't use `\protected@write` to write the label to the aux-file, and so it explodes because greek redefines roman.

Comment: Aldo, the issue doesn’t happen with the class `article`.

Comment: sure, \frontmatter is book specific (and that is the command that changes the page numbering to roman).

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer, that helped a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ulrike pointed out the issue that `lastpage`has and which should be corrected by its author, so perhaps you should file a bug report with him.

The LaTeX Companion, 3rd edition, suggests the following as an alternative to lastpage:

```
\AddToHook{shipout/lastpage}{\label{LastPage}}
```

If you add this to the preamble instead of loading the package it might be all that is needed for your use case.

Comment: My distribution is too old I think and `\AddToHook` is an "Undefined control sequence". Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Colas in that case you have to see  that lastpage.sty gets fixed (which would be helpful anyway) --- but perhaps updating your distribution isn't a bad idea either